# Is there a cmdlet to test for Azure web app url?

Tags: powershell, azure

Is there a way to test with PowerShell if a Web App URL (https://[whatever].azurewebsites.net) already exists.

It seems there was a way using Test-AzureName, but that seems to be no longer available.

thanks.

Comment: Please show your effort on what you have tried so far. I have directed you with an answer. Please have a look and understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Ranadip's solution works.  You can also use

```
test-connection https://[whatever].azurewebsites.net
```

When you try and create a webapp in the Azure Portal it will test to make sure your webapp is unique and if you deploy via ARM template or PowerShell you will error out if you are not unique.

Comment: It seems Test-Connection is for pinging the URL however ICMP traffic is blocked by Azure by default I believe so this doesn't actually work.

Answer (score -1):

You can check with Invoke-webrequest.

You can do like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://[whatever].azurewebsites.net -Method Get
```

You can test that as a sample with google.com like:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://www.google.com -Method Get
```

And you can check the status code of 200 if it is returning properly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will let you know how I go.